# Can you use dd command on a CFAST?

Tags: sd-card, dd, copy

I know you can use the `dd` command to copy a CF card to your hard drive but can the same be done to a CFAST card?

Comment: Be warned that dd is very powerful but also very dangerous. It does what you tell it to do without any questions, so if you tell it to wipe your family pictures ... and it is a small typing error away. So you must know what you are doing, and you should check and double check, that everything is correct. There are tools available, that can make things safer. - In this case, what do you want to do - make a [compressed] image as a complete backup, or something else? Or do you want to clone the system from the card to the hard disk drive, which means that you overwrite everything on that drive?

Comment: I had a CF card that I had to return in a few days so I wanted to make a exact copy of that CF card. So, I used a spare CF card and the DD command to copy it byte for byte and its 3 partitions onto the blank one. Then I thought, if I had a CFAST card, could  I potentially do the same thing? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

`dd` is not specific to copying data from one kind of media to a file on your disk. Its job is to copy (part of) the contents of one file into (parts of) a different file.

- `dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/image.img` copies the contents of your hard drive (if it's `/dev/sda` which it probably is) into the file `/mnt/image.img`.
- `dd if=/mnt/image.img of=/dev/sda` copies the contents of `/mnt/image.img` onto your hard drive. Note that you probably don't want to do this if `/mnt/image.img` isn't an old image of your hard drive you want to restore (and that you should always do this in a live session, same regarding the previous command).
- `dd if=~/Documents/someFile of=~/Documents/copyOfThatFile` creates a copy of the file `someFile` in your `Documents` folder.
- `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda` copies the contents of `/dev/urandom` (which spits out pseudorandom data, as much as you want) onto your hard drive.
- `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sda` copies the contents of the first partition of your hard drive onto your hard drive which is probably the worst idea of all.

Whether the storage medium you use is a CF card, a CFAST card, a HDD, an SSD, a random thumb drive you picked up, or something virtual like a RAM disk or a RAID doesn't matter. The medium merely has to be supported by your system.

Note that you probably should specify the block size to something bigger than the default size to speed the process of copying up. You can do this by adding `bs=8M` to the command to set the block size to 8 MiB. The default block size of 512 Byte is very small for modern hardware and only that small for historical reasons.

Comment: Well sometimes depending on what you have installed at boot I have on rare occassions had a drive not my primary hard drive end as /dev/sda. This seems to happen depending on order the kernel sees drives. Before I run dd I always try to be extra careful with lsblk to make sure I am not going to end up copying data directly to my main hard disk.

Comment: @ianorlin I wrote "which it probably is". This kind of means that it's not necessarily `/dev/sda` but in most cases, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Any storage device can be imaged to/from your hard drive using `dd`, providing that the Linux kernel recognizes it as a block device.

Whether or not the Linux kernel will recognize it depends on the model of the card reader.

If the card reader shows up when you plug it in, and you are able to see files on it, then `dd` will work.